# Hibernate open session in view vs EclipseLink lazy loading

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, lazy-loading

**tl;dr** : *I see a lot of people giving advice not to use OpenSessionInView for hibernate. Does EclipseLink approach to lazy loading suffers from the same critics ?*

---

I'm trying out hibernate after using EclipseLink for a while. I was at first shocked to have a `LazyInitializationException`, which EclipseLink takes care off out of the box. After gathering informations, here is my understanding of what happens behind the scene :

**EclipseLink**
When trying to access fields that have to be lazy loaded, it finds the entity manager in the pool and make the databases queries from there.

**Hibernate**
When using openSessionInView the session stays open till the view is generated.

I find the EclipseLink approach far better and I wonder why hibernate didn't take that one or if it could be implemented in it. As far as I understand, if a field has to be populated through an ajax request after the view has been rendered that wouldn't work with hibernate even with openSessionInView set to true. Also I feel like keeping the session active could be a bottleneck but my understanding is too rough to be trusted. While EclipseLink simply "close" the connection, put it back in the pool and gets it as needed.

So to the point:

- **Open session in view is [not recommended](http://blog.jhades.org/open-session-in-view-pattern-pros-and-cons/). Does EclipseLink approach to lazy loading suffers from the same critics ?**
  *I understand the n+1 problem but I feel like that it can be taken care off easily with logging queries and modifying the code accordingly. So even though eclipseLink suffers from that as well it's no biggie.*
- Are there pros and cons to both approach ? Or only cons for hibernate's approach ?
- Is there a way of making hibernate take EclipseLink approach ? I've read that hibernate is more performant than EclipseLink, ence the question.

Comment: 1. I use this pattern (later Hibernate, now Eclipselink + Wicket/Tomcat), application has no too much scale (intranets) 2. Apologise with blog: sometimes concrete data atoms are not known at architect level: may be included or excluded by template (frontend) developer